# any way in exim to automatically delete failed messages?

Tags: email-server, exim, email-bounces, message-queuing

Is there any way to configure my exim to delete messages automatically that
bounce or have errors instead of them getting frozen and accumulating in the
queue? i am getting lots of massage in queue name frozen.

Thank You,
Radhe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a setting that determines how long those frozen messages are kept until they are deleted:

```
# exim -bP | grep frozen
timeout_frozen_after = 1w
```

Check to see what yours is set to and adjust it downward to a lower value.  More documentation is available at [Exim Docs Chapter 14](http://www.exim.org/exim-html-current/doc/html/spec_html/ch-main_configuration.html), search for the word "frozen" on that page and see all of the ways you can change the handling of frozen messages.

Comment: if i don't want any massage in queue more than a day then where to serch and edit?

Comment: Find where timeout_frozen_after is set and set it to '1d' for "1 day".